# Numpy-ish way to count intersection size of two uneven numpy arrays with weights

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a numpy-ish way to count intersection size of two uneven numpy arrays with weights. I have two numpy arrays of ints of the form:

```
arr1=[[item11,count11],[item12,count12],[item13,count13],...]
arr2=[[item21,count21],[item22,count22],[item23,count23],...]
```

Let's say that these arrays summarize people's grocery lists, where each element is of the form [itemX, countY] and denotes that a person bought countY copies of itemX. The arrays are of different lengths and unsorted, because different people might buy different items and items that someone didn't buy are not on their grocery list.

I'd like to count the number of items that appear in both arr1 and arr2, weighting them by the minimum count. For example [item1,count1] is in arr1 and [item1, count2] is in arr2, I want to add min(count1,count2) to the sum total.

A non-numpy code for this would be:

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(arr1)):
  for j in range(len(arr2)):
   if arr1[i][0] == arr2[j][0]:
     count += min(arr1[i][1], arr2[j][1])
return count
```

Example:

```
arr1 = [[1,10],[2,100],[3,1000],[4,10000]]
arr2 = [[1,10],[3,100],[4,1000],[5,10000],[6,99]]
```

Should return 1110, because 1 appears in both lists 10 times, 3 appears in both lists 100 times, and 4 appears in both lists 1000 times.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to return 1110? is that 1,110? or what does it mean? There is no 1110 in the  list

Comment: 1110 is the weighted intersection size, it's what is returned by the pseudocode I provided

Comment: So its the sum of all the values?

Comment: It's the weighted sum of the values - please refer to the code in the post for a formal specification :)

Comment: What do you mean by weighted sum? Check the answer I provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = dict(arr1)
b = dict(arr2)
sum([min([a[i], b[i]]) for i in set(a).intersection(b)])
1110
```

Using numpy:

import numpy as np

```
np1 = np.array(arr1).T
np2 = np.array(arr2).T
both = np.intersect1d(np1[0], np2[0])
np.minimum(np1[1, np.in1d(np1[0], both)], np2[1, np.in1d(np2[0], both)]).sum()
1110
```

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(arr1).merge(pd.DataFrame(arr2),on=0).set_index(0).min(1).sum()
1110
```